# Solr/Lucene "kit" to test searching?

Tags: templates, solr, lucene

Is there a "code free" way to get SOLR/LUCENE (or something similar) pointed at a set of word docs to make them quickly searchable by a user?

I am prototyping, seeing if there is value in, a system to search through some homegrown news articles. Before I stand up code to handle search string input and document indexing, I wanted to see if it was even worth it before I starting trying to figure it all out.

Thanks,

Judd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bin/post` tool of Solr and the Tika handler (named the ExtractingRequestHandler), you should be able to get something up and running for prototyping rather quickly.

See the introduction of [Uploading Data with Solr Cell using Apache Tika](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika). Tika is used to process a wide range of different document types.

You can [give the Solr post tool a directory or a list of files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool) to submit to the index.

> Automatically detect content types in a folder, and recursively scan it for documents for indexing into gettingstarted.
>
> `bin/post -c gettingstarted afolder/`

Comment: That seems great for indexing. How do I send in a search request without generating code?

Comment: If you go to `http://localhost:8983/solr` you can play around with the API. There is also the [Velocity Search UI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Velocity+Search+UI) which is a templatized search application you can play around with. To integrate it with your own, custom app, you'll have to use a Solr client, which depending on the language of choice will vary.

Comment: I was hoping for a "put your directory into this config file and off you go". But your pointers moved me in the right direction. Thanks.